# Manga about miniature people piloting cloned women

Tags: story-identification, horror, manga, mecha

There’s a really disturbing manga that I remember reading in 2020, but for the love of all things, I can’t remember the title. However, I remember the story.

It’s about people who pilot these things that resemble human women, but are partially mechanical, kinda like Evangelion, but way more screwed up. It’s later revealed that the people piloting these things are actually tiny after a group of people from the present day wake up and encounter them, and then it ends with them pulling a plug to a giant computer.

Comment: Probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267667/manga-featuring-miniature-people-using-normal-sized-human-cyborgs-for-labor-and

Answer (score 3):

*Conductive Brains Parataxis*. I read it before, it featured cloned 'giants' and they were used as transport and work, like mechs/vehicles. The mini people were unplugged as you say if I remember correctly.