# Manga featuring miniature people using normal sized human cyborgs for labor and as vehicles

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember seeing pictures of pages of a Manga a few years ago that contained exactly what was described in the title. I thought I first encountered it while on TVtropes, but I can't find it on any of the pages that I thought might lead me to it.

I remember two images in particular:
What I think was some sort of hanger where those human cyborgs (which I think had heads covered by machinery) were standing around, and a scene involving what looked car that had human hands coming out of it, which I assume meant there was one of the normal-sized humans was being used as a vehicle.

I never actually read it since it disturbed me at the time, but it popped back into my mind and I would like to find it so that I can now read it. Any help figuring out the name is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242827/manga-about-miniature-people-piloting-cloned-women ? There's no answer, but if they are the same it adds some extra details.

Answer (score 8):

This is super late but I hope you see this. The manga is called *Choudennou Parataxis*, or *Super-Conductive Brains Parataxis* (2001), by the mangaka Shintaro Kago. Its TVTropes page is [here](https://tvtropes.org/Manga/SuperConductiveBrainsParataxis).

> In a future age, giant humanoid creatures called Surdlers are used as basis for cyborgs that are employed in transportation, warfare, and construction. They are cloned and mass-produced like machines, and treated as such by societies, but some of them seem to have vestiges of their original minds. The story starts when one such Surdler breaks free of its mechanical constraints and runs amok, and follows the effects the event has on society from there.